# ASP.NET CORE 3.1 Cookie always work even I restart the program

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationSchema, principal);
//...

//Then 

HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationSchema);
return Redirect ……
```

I saw it let cookie expire at once. Use set-cookie : XXXX 1970 XXXX in response header.
But when I add cookie through chrome f12 application cookies, I found it still work.
Even when I restart the program,

```
this.context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

is true. The cookie still work...

Answer (score 0):

If the cookie persists in the browser session. This persistence can only be enabled if the user explicitly agrees and checks the "remember me" checkbox or similar mechanism when logging in.Like this code example:

```
// using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;

await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
    new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        IsPersistent = true
    });
```

This code snippet creates an identity and corresponding cookies, which persist after the browser is closed. Any previously configured sliding expiration settings will be respected. If the cookie expires when the browser is closed, the browser will clear the cookie after restarting.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: I have not set IsPersistent to true. This interface is designed for that. The cookie will be unuseable until its expire time.